# Pre-emptive Solution for 'The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)'

Tags: c++, windows

My c++ winapi application is outputting the following error when running on certain computers.

> The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)

Is there anything I can do to avoid this error? Or is the problem that the user's Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package is not properly configured? This error has occurred on users using Windows 10.

I currently compile my application on my 64bit Windows 8.1 OS. The win32 visual-studio project is compiled using the following project properties:

- Character Set: Unicode char set
- Use of MFC: Use standard windows libraries
- Whole Program Optimisation: Use Link Time Code Generation
- Debug info format: none
- Code Generation->Runtime library: /MT

Comment: @BoPersson the question is what can I/a developer do to avoid/solve this error, if anything, on my end at compilation/distribution time. The supposed duplicate 'already answered' question doesn't address my question, it only gives a solution for the end user experiencing the problem.

Comment: As a developer you could make sure that the end user isn't experiencing the problem by delivering the required runtime with the application. Like it is commented to the answer: *"The redistributable contains libraries which your program may require. Programs will typically install it during their installation process"*